# how can I apply the NSLayoutConstraints to the element so that it is always in the middle of the element below him?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

In my storyboard I have a `MapView` stretched to the borders of my screen. But there's a possibility to show up the keyboard, so then I update the constraints and the map shrinks in height.

This is my method responsible for that:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    if(isKeyboardShown == true)
    {
        bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - endFrame.origin.y+49
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        isKeyboardShown = false
    } else {
        bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - endFrame.origin.y
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        isKeyboardShown = true
    }
}
```

It works fine. Now I want to add the `UIImageView` that is always centered on the map, no matter if the keyboard is visible or not. I thought it's enough to center the image in the perfect center of the map.

It so far looks like this:

[image]

I managed to add somehow the constraint on the `Y` axis:

[image]

but what about `X`?

I tried adding it here:

[image]

but the `align` option is greyed out...

How can I add constraints so that the image is always centered no matter how the map is shrinked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ctrl+dragging from the image view to the map, and clicking `Center Horizontally`.

You also might have a conflict with your `Top Space to: Top Layout...` constraint and your `Align Center Y to: Map View` constraint. It sounds like you just want the center Y constraint, since when your map grows / shrinks your image won't always be 192 from the top if it's centered on the map.

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought! :)